# Reflection in OpenEdge ABL / Progress 4GL

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I am not able to find anything on reflection in OpenEdge ABL and how to do it. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible. There are not as many possibilities in OpenEdge as in languagaes like Java or C#, but since version 11 it has basic functionality.

To use reflection look at `Progress.Lang.Object` which has a method `GetClass()` that returns an instance of `Progress.Lang.Class`.

These are the members of `Progress.Lang.Class` from the OpenEdge Help (Version 11.1, should be the same for all 11.x versions):

[image]

In earlier versions of OpenEdge the reflection capabilities were even worse. But it was possible to invoke methods and create instances dynamically.

You should also have a look at the `DYNAMIC-NEW` statement and the `DYNAMIC-INVOKE` function.

Answer (score 1):

It hasn't been implemented yet.

Comment: I see. Think i need to reflect on the choices one makes in life and programming languages... :-)

Comment: Keep in mind there's lots of other stuff the ABL can do that other languages can't! :)

Answer (score 1):

And don't forget the GET-SIGNATURE() method and the INTERNAL-ENTRIES attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for Reflection in OpenEdge ABL in 2021 and I found that there are more possibilities now (I'm using OE 11.6). I wasn't able to find extensive documentation but here is a start: https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-oo-abl-develop-applications/page/Reflection.html

When using Progress Developer Studio you will able to see the possibilities when using auto-complete (Ctrl + Space).
[image]